# Как из vector int8_t получить int число?

Tags: c++, типы-данных, преобразование

Допустим есть вот такой вектор:

```
vector<int8_t> foo = {-128, -50, 0, 0}; // 52864
```

Как из него получить число 52864?
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: https://ideone.com/zqB4S4 В ответ не выставляю из-за ревнителей чистоты, которые тут же скажут, что это UB :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ первый, не вызывающий вопросов...

```
vector<signed char> foo = {-128, -50, 0, 0};

unsigned int r = (unsigned char)foo[0] + ((unsigned char)foo[1] << 8) +
                 ((unsigned char)foo[2] << 16) + ((unsigned char)foo[3] << 24);

cout << r << endl;
```

Способ второй, короткий, на который ревнители стандарта могут ругаться...

```
cout << *(int*)foo.data() << endl;;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Второй вариант мне нравится больше :)

Comment: @Harry 
Подскажите где про это читать? Я целый день гуглил, ничего не нагуглил

Comment: Представление чисел в памяти компьютера, + описание вектора, + битовые операции...

Comment: @Tim, также погуглите: undefined behavior + strict aliasing rule + alignment requirements bus error + big endian machine

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Не знаю, меня уже дрожь бьет, если пытаюсь хоть какое-то приведение делать :) Бьет, если на ruSO, в жизни же еще ни разу с этими проблемами не сталкивался, надо сказать... Что-то никак не пойму, что именно можно, а что нет. Стойкое ощущение надуманности проблемы...